# Need to add a tab between a certain code and text (Notepad++)

Tags: notepad++

I have 100Q-1666 Mist Lava Solids

I need 100Q-1666 [TAB] Mist Lava Solids

Anyone have any ideas please? Tried at random a few different codes but have failed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\d+[A-Z]-\d+\K\h+`
- Replace with: `\t`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    \d+     # 1 or more digits
    [A-Z]   # 1 uppercase
    -       # 1 dash
    \d+     # 1 or more digits
    \K      # forget all we have seen until this position
    \h+     # 1 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Replacement:**

```
\t          # a tabulation
```

**Result for given example:**

```
100Q-1666   Mist Lava Solids
```

Comment: @JB: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, see: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers